# oras push command with --manifest-config & --manifest-annotations options is not working

Tags: docker, azure-container-registry

I installed (OCI Registry As Storage) ORAS 0.14.1 referring to the URL https://oras.land/cli/ successfully.

I also pushed & pulled artifact to & from Azure Container Registry using the below commands **successfully**.

```
oras push myacr.azurecr.io/devops/projectname/cli/linux:474438 D:\home\vsts\work\1\a\projectname\publish\linux-x64\projectcfg


oras pull myacr.azurecr.io/devops/projectname/cli/linux:474388
```

I tried the following commands to pass manifest config and annotations along with oras push, referring to the below URLs.

https://oras.land/cli/3_manifest_config/

https://oras.land/cli/4_manifest_annotations/

```
oras push --manifest-config D:\runtimeLinux64-annotations.json myacr.azurecr.io/devops/projectname/cli/linux:474438 D:\home\vsts\work\1\a\projectname\publish\linux-x64\projectcfg


oras push --manifest-annotations D:\runtimeLinux64-annotations.json myacr.azurecr.io/devops/projectname/cli/linux:474438 D:\home\vsts\work\1\a\projectname\publish\linux-x64\projectnamecfg
```

But I got the following errors.

**Error: unknown flag: --manifest-config**

**Error: unknown flag: --manifest-annotations**

What am I missing here?

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is a breaking change in v0.14.0. Precisely,

--manifest-config is renamed to --config

--manifest-annotations is renamed to --annotation-file

Documentation is not updated yet on the oras.land website.